# Snap on Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, snap

I've been using Kubuntu with Snap for quite a while and no bigger issues so far.
Today all my snap apps stopped launching, reporting the following error:

```
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope is not a snap cgroup
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a recent issue and hopefully if a bug will get fixed soon.
I am running KDE on MX 21 Wildflower (in `systemd` mode to enable snap) and so have a similar OS as you.

I found a few references that I used to figure out the fix:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cannot-launch-snap-applications-with-cgroup-v2/27700/2

https://github.com/Yubico/yubioath-desktop/issues/763

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977607/grub-error-systemd-unified-cgroup-hierarchy-0-not-found

==

The main fix(es) appear to be to install `dbus-user-session`, and to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file with this line: (as sudo or root)

1. try:

   sudo apt install dbus-user-session
2. (first back up your `/etc/default/grub` file)

Then edit the line in /etc/default/grub as follows:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=1"
```

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Hopefully this works for you and I will follow this thread to see how it goes for others.

Comment: I am having the [same issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/696600/38529). But it didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was to "correct" the environment variable `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` to this:

`export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/bus"`

then run your snap and check the result.

[Source](https://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/snap-problem-solving.html)